# C# how to switch between databases

Tags: c#, sql, database

Alright this is completely baffling me.  how do i switch between db's using C#?  The below doesn't work.  I also tried it using in SQL mgmt studio and it appears that Go needs to be on a line by itself to work.

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = @"USE [" + db + "] GO";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have 2 connection strings then reference which one you need at the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`GO` is not part of SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx), that is something special Sql Server Management Studio (and some other Microsoft utilities) uses, it marks the seperation of "batches". Every GO would translate in to a `ExecuteXXXXQuery` action in C#.

I am assuming your code is more than what you posted so lets say your original query was

```
select * into #t from foo 
use [someOtherDatabase]
GO
insert into foo select * from #t
```

What this would be come in C# is

```
using(var cmd = SqlCommand("", connectionString))
{
    cmd.CommandText = @"select * into #t from foo
                        use [someOtherDatabase]";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into foo select * from #t";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be trying to change the database in the context of the command object, you should change it at the SqlConnection level. See this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.changedatabase%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The connection string on your connection object will name a database. You should use a new connection object that refers to the new database.

Comment: Prolly more sensible than changing dbs on the fly, +1